# Python plugins not available, OS X 10.10.5, QGIS 2.8.4

Tags: python, osx, plugins

I’m using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and QGIS 2.8.4 Wien.

My mainproblem is that python support is disabled and I can’t use python plugins. QGIS seems to act fine and I’ve done a lot of work with QGIS.

In the next step I’ll need several plugins, but there isn’t any python plugins avaible. When I open Plugin Manager and take a look at “Settings”, I get a note “The settings on this tab are only applicable for Python Plugins. No Python support detected, thus no settings available.”

I have installed QGIS for three times according to this instruction http://www.konstantingreger.net/setting-up-qgis-2-8-on-macos-x-10-10-yosemite/ .

I’ve tried to solve this issue by entering “sudo rm -rf .qgis2″ into my terminal solved the issue. This is not the solution for this issue.

When I start QGIS this window comes up:

```
[ERROR] Can not make qgis.db private copy.
```

After that this window comes up:

```
  Couldn’t load qgis.user.
  Python support will be disabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/user.py", line 41, in
    os.makedirs(expressionspath)
File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/MyUserName/.qgis2'
Python verson:
2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]

QGIS verson:
2.8.4-Wien 'Wien', exported

Python path:
['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', u'/Users/MyUserName/.qgis2/python', u'/Users/MyUserName/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python/2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL', u'/Users/MyUserName/.qgis2//python']
```

Comment: Finally I found the solution. I had to create new .bash_profile file in the Terminal by typing
   nano .bash_profile

Then I added two commands
   export PATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
   export PYTHONPATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python"

After saving these lines I typed
   source .bash_profile
to activete my new .bash_profile file.