# I can't install any plugins on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, installation

I just installed QGIS 3.4 on my computer (macOS Sierra 10.12.6) and I'm trying to install QuickMapServices, but I'm unable to. My plugins window looks like this:

[image: QGIS plugins]

and the settings tab says "The settings on this tab are only applicable for Python Plugins. No Python support detected, thus no settings available":

[image: settings]

I downloaded QuickMapServices from the QGIS Python Plugin Repository, but I can't access it. I have Python 3.6.0 on my computer.

Comment: May be it's a PYTHONPATH problem reported and solved here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/189248/87346

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem? I’m having the same problem. I tried the solution offered in the link eurojam posted but it didn’t work for me. Here is my question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341486/unable-to-install-plugins-in-qgis-3-10-for-mac-no-python-support-detected

Answer (score 2):

Update your Mac OS to High Sierra 10.13 or higher. This worked for me.

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Windows while using QGIS 3.16. So this is for anyone using Windows.

Check this site on installing Python packages
https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/

You might realize you are missing the following .dll files

- api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0
- api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0

Install them then proceed with the installation provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux the following helped: `install qgis-server python-qgis qgis`

```bash
# Debian-based, as e.g. Ubuntu    
if [ -f "/etc/debian_version" ]; then
    sudo apt install qgis-server python-qgis qgis
fi

# Red-Hat-Based, as e.g. Fedora:
if [ "$(grep -Ei 'fedora|redhat' /etc/*release)" ]; then
    sudo dnf install qgis-server python-qgis qgis
fi
```